# "Insufficient privileges" while shutting down as sysoper

Tags: oracle, permissions, oracle-12c

I can't shutdown the database with a common user that is granted sysoper.

There is clearly a discrepancy between this and PDBs that I am unaware of (and that the documentation also doesn't clarify), since if I do the same operations for PDB users a sysoper can shutdown/startup the PDB with no problem. Other examples I've looked at also indicate that nothing should be wrong. What am I missing?

Exact error message is:

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Thanks for any insights.

[image: Insufficient privileges as sysoper]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends upon how you have granted the `SYSOPER` privilege. To shutdown the database instance user should have `SYSOPER` privilege on all containers.

The following demonstrate the scenario.

I have common user call `C##_TEST`.

```
[oracle@ora12c dbs]$ sqlplus sys@oracdb as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Fri Dec 2 08:47:05 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options


SQL> select common from dba_users where username='C##_TEST';

COM
---
YES
```

I have granted `SYSOPER` to the user for the `ORACDB`(CDB) only.

```
SQL> grant sysoper to c##_test container=current;

Grant succeeded.
```

Then I have connected to container database using C##_TEST user as `SYSOPER` and tried to shut down the database and got the `ORA-01031` error.

```
[oracle@ora12c dbs]$ sqlplus c##_test/test@oracdb as sysoper

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Fri Dec 2 08:49:05 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> shut immediate;
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
SQL>
```

Now I again granted the `SYSOPER` privilege with the option `container=all`. And this time the user can shut down the database.

```
[oracle@ora12c dbs]$ sqlplus sys@oracdb as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Fri Dec 2 08:49:36 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> grant sysoper to c##_test container=all;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options

[oracle@ora12c dbs]$ sqlplus c##_test/test@oracdb as sysoper

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Fri Dec 2 08:50:06 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> shut immediate;
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
```

Comment: Perfect - that is what I was missing. I realize now what I overlooked - it makes sense that a common user that spans all of the DBs would therefore have to have privileges for all of them too. Thanks!